# How can I copy and paste from a closed workbook to the active workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I was able to make a program that opens the workbook that copies and pastes into a workbook that is called in this case "ALL WIP". However, to make this more convenient, I would like it so no matter which workbook you run this in, it will copy and paste into that specific workbook. Thanks.

```
Sub AddMaskLevels()

Dim book

Set book = Workbooks.Open("MaskLevels.xlsx")

Dim x As Workbook

Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks("MaskLevels.xlsx")'Where the information is copied from'

Set y = Workbooks("ALL WIP.xlsm")'I want to make this into the active workbook'

x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A81").Copy

y.Sheets("All WIP").Columns(9).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 'The Sheet and column will always stay the same'

x.Save

x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not completely clear on the process. Where is this macro residing? In *MaskLevels.xlsx*? If so, then why are you opening itself  and you want to dynamically change this to any workbook? If not, what is *MaskLevels.xlsx*?

Comment: Just explain what you want to do and let more experienced people help you with that, and of course you need to show that you have tried and failed, show the error you get

Comment: @Parfait MaskLevels.xlsx is the closed workbook that I would like to get my information from. I would like to paste the information into the workbook I ran the macro from whether it is Workbook1.xls, Workbook2.xls, ALL WIP.xls, ect.

Comment: Try `x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy` and `y.Worksheets("All WIP").bla.bla.PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy from `MaskLevels.xlsx` into whatever workbook the macro is running from, try:

```
Sub AddMaskLevels()
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim x As Workbook
    Set y = ThisWorkbook
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("MaskLevels.xlsx")

    x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A81").Copy
    y.Sheets("All WIP").Columns(9).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    'Close the workbook (no need to save it - hopefully nothing was changed)
    x.Close False
End Sub
```

---

If you want to copy from `MaskLevels.xlsx` into whatever workbook is active when you run the macro, try:

```
Sub AddMaskLevels()
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim x As Workbook
    Set y = ActiveWorkbook
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("MaskLevels.xlsx")

    x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A81").Copy
    y.Sheets("All WIP").Columns(9).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    'Close the workbook (no need to save it - hopefully nothing was changed)
    x.Close False
End Sub
```